# Apache webserver is not listening to port 443

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server

So far I did this, enabled ssl by this command `a2enmod ssl` and inside /etc/apache2/listen.conf added

```
Listen 80
<IfDefine SSL>
    <IfDefine !NOSSL>
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>
    </IfDefine>
```

Then stopped apache then started and restarted multiple times but no service is running/listening to port 443. How can I make it work?

I am using LinuxOpenSUSE.

Comment: you could save all the hassle if you removed all the IfDefine/IfModule orgy tags you have in there.

Comment: I suggest you do another virtualhost that listen on port 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ezra-s suggested, removing all those tags did the trick. Now I just have following two lines without the tags and it is working just fine.

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

Comment: Please accept you own answer in order to confirm that this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To finally enable SSL the server needs to be started with the flag "SSL". To do so, call `a2enflag SSL`

Answer (score 0):

One more  `</IfDefine>`

is missing in your example. Maybe that has something to do with it.

```
Listen 80
<IfDefine SSL>
    <IfDefine !NOSSL>
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>
    </IfDefine>
</IfDefine>         <-- this one?
```

Comment: Where do I add this </IfDefine>? Could you show the details